# jQuery popups within an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, imagemap

I would like to build an image map and call jQuery popups based on the area of the image map that is clicked. Can this be done?

Something similar to this tutorial, except the `href` would call a jQuery popup ="#MyPopupName".
[HTML <area> href Attribute Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_href.asp)

Here's what I have so far (that doesn't work):

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
    <p>Hello, this is the CONTINENTS navigation page.</p>

    <a href="#Popup_NAmerica" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Click for N America</a>
    <p><img src="Assets/images/World_Map_1930_Continents.png" width="1024" height="553" alt="Continents Map" usemap="imgmap_continents" /> </p>

    <!-- href map -->
    <map name="imgmap_continents">
        <area shape="rect" coords="12,38,279,270" href="#Popup_NAmerica" /> <!--N America popoup -->
        <area shape="rect" coords="126,289,327,548" href="#Popup_SAmerica" /> <!--S America popup -->
        <area shape="rect" coords="849,371,1007,498" href="#Popup_SAmerica" /> <!--Australia popup -->
        <area shape="poly" coords="379,176,564,180,643,294,641,468,481,471,473,330,389,318,423,420" href="#Popup_Africa" /> <!--Africa popup -->
        <!-- Europe, Asia, Antartica go here -->
    </map>


    <!-- POPUPS -->

    <div data-role="popup" id="Popup_NAmerica" class="ui-content">
        <h3>North America</h3>
        <p>This is where there will be both an <strong>ON</strong> and <strong>OFF</strong> button for this country.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="Popup_SAmerica" class="ui-content">
        <h3>South America</h3>
        <p>This is where there will be both an <strong>ON</strong> and <strong>OFF</strong> button for this country.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="Popup_Australia" class="ui-content">
        <h3>Australia</h3>
        <p>This is where there will be both an <strong>ON</strong> and <strong>OFF</strong> button for this country.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="Popup_Africa" class="ui-content">
        <h3>Africa</h3>
        <p>This is where there will be both an <strong>ON</strong> and <strong>OFF</strong> button for this country.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Europe, Asia, Antartica go here -->
    <!-- /POPUPS -->
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0wnvuxk/

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be worth detailing what does not work exactly, compared to your expected behaviour. A very good practice is also to reproduce the issue online (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) so that people can directly modify your code and provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0wnvuxk/

Comment: You can use Jquery qTip2: http://qtip2.com/demos

Answer (score -1):

You have an incorrect `usemap` attribute to start with: there is a missing hash `#` before the map name.

Then it seems that jQuery Mobile automatically attaches the popup opening feature only on `a` links, not on `area`'s. Therefore you will have to create an event listener yourself:

```js
$("area", "map[name='imgmap_continents']").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    // See jQuery Mobile Popup API
    // https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/

    // Use the following instruction to open the popup where it is defined.
    //$(href).popup("open");

    // Use the following instruction to emulate a click on the button
    // that opens the popup. This will open the popup on top of that
    // button instead of where it is defined.
    $("a[href='" + href + "']").click();

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a0wnvuxk/9/